# Focus() is not working in ionic using ios 10 safari browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ionic-framework, safari

focus() is not working in `ionic` using ios `10 safari browser`.

It works when you use `chrome emulator` but not when use **`ios 10 safari browser`**.

below is the code i'm using to focus element.

```
var rvMobileApp = angular.module('rvMobileApp.shared.directive');
rvMobileApp.directive('rvSetFocus', function ($timeout) {
   return {
           link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

           $timeout(function () {
               element[0].focus();
           }, 100);
        }
};
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: What about other browsers? did you ever check it or not?

Comment: What type of element is element[0]?

Comment: It is an input element ( textbox ).

Comment: I have checked in desktop browsers this works but when I open it in mobile phone ( IOS 10 Safari) it does not focus input element.

Comment: @RahulRai can also confirm this. It's an iOS 10 specific issue, even in wrapping it in a setTimeout of 2 seconds. I'm tempted to say it's an iOS 10 bug.

Comment: @Prisoner I don't think so that it is an issue of iOS 10  alone.I have tried .foucs() without  using Ionic libraries it works perfectly fine with iOS 10. I don't  know somewhere .focus  method is getting override by ionic. This does not work only when we use ionic and iOS 10 safari browser. For other bowers combination with ionic .focus works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

By default iOS does not allow any keyboard interaction except for when an input field is tapped.

To override this, you need to put this in you config.xml:

```
<preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="false" />
```

Comment: we are not using cordova so we can not use this solution.